# Vapor Barrier Plastic over upside down crawlspace Insulation

Tags: crawlspace

I bought a rambler built in 1972.  Had guys replace the insulation.  Inspector came and said they put it in upside down.  It's a shallow crawlspace and would be a mess to tear off paper and hard to turn over.  Can I put a plastic vapor barrier the insulation to keep moisture & pest out? I can't afford to take it all down and start over.  Thank you for any help, Lisa

Comment: If a contractor did this incorrect work, they are responsible to fix it at no cost, you are not responsible.

Comment: It was put in by workers who are no longer around.  DIY project.

Comment: ok. Have you considered asking the inspector this question? He is the one who will have to approve it

Comment: what is a rambler?   I thought a rambler was a car.